# How can I have my form display data items from an SQL Access document one row at a time in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to make a Windows Forms application that allows a user to retrieve data from an SQL Access document and display them onto a form one at a time. I will have to have a button that allows them to see the next set of data items within the row of the SQL table. That part would be easy for me except I do not know how to separate my SQL data items by what is in the row. Here is my code.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myconnstr = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data Source=ordertest.mdb";     // the msaccess connect string
        string mysql = "select sku, description, quantityonhand, quantityonorder, warehouse from inventory;";  // my sql query

        OleDbConnection dbconn;

        dbconn = new OleDbConnection(myconnstr);       // created connection object using connect string
        dbconn.Open();                              // my connection

        OleDbCommand dbcmd = new OleDbCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = mysql;                 
        dbcmd.Connection = dbconn;

        OleDbDataReader myreader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();   // execute sql statement, put results in datareader       
        while (myreader.Read())     // this is where I get my rows and loop them until they're all processed, is it something I need to do with this?
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + myreader["sku"].ToString();
            richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + myreader["description"].ToString();
            richTextBox3.Text = richTextBox3.Text + myreader["quantityonhand"].ToString();
            richTextBox4.Text = richTextBox4.Text + myreader["quantityonorder"].ToString() + '\n';
            richTextBox5.Text = richTextBox5.Text + myreader["warehouse"].ToString() + '\n';

        }   // end of while

        dbconn.Close();
    }
```

If it helps, my sku, quantityonhand, and quantityonorder are ints while description and warehouse are strings.

Comment: Are you aware of the capabilities of the DataGridView?  Or DataTables? Or a BindingNavigator?

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around it. I really haven't worked with SQLs at all and this was kinda dumped on me.

Comment: Well, now you have some terms to feed into Google. *Plenty* of good things on MSDN